# Can't get wifi working on Aspire E15 E5-571G-35NW

Tags: drivers, wireless, aspire

I wanted to start learning linux. So I installed ubuntu on my old laptop which was using Windows previously. After installation I realized that I can't connect to wifi. Ubuntu's options only include wired network connection options. When I had Windows on this computer the wifi worked fine.
I tried searching around for fixes but nothing seemed to work. Then I tried reinstalling ubuntu thinking that it was a installation bug but it still doesn't work.

Maybe someone can help me with this problem.

Options menu
[image: Options menu]

```
mashas@mashas-Aspire-E5:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 0b)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 0b)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 0b)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1c.0 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 3 (rev e4)
00:1c.3 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 4 (rev e4)
00:1c.4 PCI bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series PCI Express Root Port 5 (rev e4)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
01:00.0 Unassigned class [ff00]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8411B PCI Express Card Reader (rev 01)
01:00.1 Ethernet controller: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 12)
02:00.0 Network controller: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n (rev 01)
03:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] (rev a1)
```

At the moment I am using usb thedering.

```
mashas@mashas-Aspire-E5:~$ sudo lshw -C network
  *-network                 
       description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0.1
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.1
       logical name: enp1s0f1
       version: 12
       serial: f0:76:1c:2d:33:60
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=5.8.0-43-generic firmware=rtl8411-2_0.0.1 07/08/13 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=MII
       resources: irq:18 ioport:4000(size=256) memory:b3504000-b3504fff memory:b3500000-b3503fff
  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: BCM43142 802.11b/g/n
       vendor: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: 01
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: memory:b3400000-b3407fff
  *-network
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 1
       bus info: usb@2:1
       logical name: usb0
       serial: 22:dc:20:0a:3c:bf
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.29 link=yes multicast=yes
```

```
########## wireless info START ##########

Report from: 16 Jul 2021 19:50 EEST +0300

Booted last: 16 Jul 2021 00:00 EEST +0300

Script from: 25 Jan 2020 03:34 UTC +0000

##### release ###########################

Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
Release:    20.04
Codename:   focal

##### kernel ############################

Linux 5.8.0-43-generic #49~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Feb 5 09:57:56 UTC 2021 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Parameters: ro, quiet, splash, vt.handoff=7

##### desktop ###########################

Ubuntu

##### lspci #############################

01:00.1 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 12)
    Subsystem: Acer Incorporated [ALI] RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [1025:0866]
    Kernel driver in use: r8169

02:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Broadcom Inc. and subsidiaries BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [14e4:4365] (rev 01)
    Subsystem: Lite-On Communications Inc BCM43142 802.11b/g/n [11ad:6645]

03:00.0 3D controller [0302]: NVIDIA Corporation GF117M [GeForce 610M/710M/810M/820M / GT 620M/625M/630M/720M] [10de:1140] (rev a1)

##### lsusb #############################

Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 04f2:b452 Chicony Electronics Co., Ltd HD WebCam
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 04ca:2009 Lite-On Technology Corp. BCM43142A0
Bus 002 Device 009: ID 04e8:6864 Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd GT-I9070 (network tethering, USB debugging enabled)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub

##### PCMCIA card info ##################

##### rfkill ############################

0: acer-wireless: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: acer-bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no

##### secure boot #######################

SecureBoot enabled

##### lsmod #############################

cfg80211              778240  0
mxm_wmi                16384  1 nouveau
acer_wmi               24576  0
wmi_bmof               16384  0
sparse_keymap          16384  1 acer_wmi
wmi                    32768  4 acer_wmi,wmi_bmof,mxm_wmi,nouveau
video                  49152  3 acer_wmi,i915,nouveau

##### interfaces ########################

##### ifconfig ##########################

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback <MAC address> brd <MAC address>
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp1s0f1: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'enp1s0f1' [IF1]> brd <MAC address>
5: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether <MAC 'usb0' [IF2]> brd <MAC address>
    inet 192.168.42.29/24 brd 192.168.42.255 scope global dynamic noprefixroute usb0
       valid_lft 3013sec preferred_lft 3013sec
    inet6 fe80::b81d:e803:2fdc:ef7f/64 scope link noprefixroute 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

##### iwconfig ##########################

lo        no wireless extensions.

enp1s0f1  no wireless extensions.

usb0      no wireless extensions.

##### route #############################

default via 192.168.42.129 dev usb0 proto dhcp metric 100 
169.254.0.0/16 dev usb0 scope link metric 1000 
192.168.42.0/24 dev usb0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.29 metric 100 

##### resolv.conf #######################

[777 root '/etc/resolv.conf' -> '../run/systemd/resolve/stub-resolv.conf']

nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad

##### network managers ##################

Installed:

    NetworkManager

Running:

root         648       1  0 19:01 ?        00:00:01 /usr/sbin/NetworkManager --no-daemon

##### NetworkManager info ###############

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         usb0
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/5
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Samsung Electronics Co., Ltd
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        GT-I9070 (network tethering, USB debugging enabled)
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         rndis_host
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 22-Aug-2005
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               RNDIS device
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'usb0' [IF2]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          100 (connected)
GENERAL.REASON:                         0 (No reason given)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               4 (full)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               3 (limited)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb2/2-1/2-1:1.0/net/usb0
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       usb0
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     Wired connection 2
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       6439afbb-afc0-3e99-80ea-279512faa919
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/ActiveConnection/3
GENERAL.METERED:                        yes (guessed)
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                yes
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               on
IP4.ADDRESS[1]:                         192.168.42.29/24
IP4.GATEWAY:                            192.168.42.129
IP4.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = 0.0.0.0/0, nh = 192.168.42.129, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = 192.168.42.0/24, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 100
IP4.ROUTE[3]:                           dst = 169.254.0.0/16, nh = 0.0.0.0, mt = 1000
IP4.DNS[1]:                             192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[1]:                        dhcp_lease_time = 3600
DHCP4.OPTION[2]:                        domain_name_servers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[3]:                        expiry = 1626457239
DHCP4.OPTION[4]:                        host_name = mashas-Aspire-E5
DHCP4.OPTION[5]:                        ip_address = 192.168.42.29
DHCP4.OPTION[6]:                        next_server = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[7]:                        requested_broadcast_address = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[8]:                        requested_domain_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[9]:                        requested_domain_name_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[10]:                       requested_domain_search = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[11]:                       requested_host_name = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[12]:                       requested_interface_mtu = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[13]:                       requested_ms_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[14]:                       requested_nis_domain = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[15]:                       requested_nis_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[16]:                       requested_ntp_servers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[17]:                       requested_rfc3442_classless_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[18]:                       requested_root_path = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[19]:                       requested_routers = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[20]:                       requested_static_routes = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[21]:                       requested_subnet_mask = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[22]:                       requested_time_offset = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[23]:                       requested_wpad = 1
DHCP4.OPTION[24]:                       routers = 192.168.42.129
DHCP4.OPTION[25]:                       subnet_mask = 255.255.255.0
IP6.ADDRESS[1]:                         fe80::b81d:e803:2fdc:ef7f/64
IP6.GATEWAY:                            --
IP6.ROUTE[1]:                           dst = fe80::/64, nh = ::, mt = 100
IP6.ROUTE[2]:                           dst = ff00::/8, nh = ::, mt = 256, table=255
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Settings/4
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTIONS[1]:   6439afbb-afc0-3e99-80ea-279512faa919 | Wired connection 2

GENERAL.DEVICE:                         enp1s0f1
GENERAL.TYPE:                           ethernet
GENERAL.NM-TYPE:                        NMDeviceEthernet
GENERAL.DBUS-PATH:                      /org/freedesktop/NetworkManager/Devices/2
GENERAL.VENDOR:                         Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
GENERAL.PRODUCT:                        RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
GENERAL.DRIVER:                         r8169
GENERAL.DRIVER-VERSION:                 5.8.0-43-generic
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-VERSION:               --
GENERAL.HWADDR:                         <MAC 'enp1s0f1' [IF1]>
GENERAL.MTU:                            1500
GENERAL.STATE:                          20 (unavailable)
GENERAL.REASON:                         2 (Device is now managed)
GENERAL.IP4-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.IP6-CONNECTIVITY:               1 (none)
GENERAL.UDI:                            /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1c.0/0000:01:00.1/net/enp1s0f1
GENERAL.IP-IFACE:                       --
GENERAL.IS-SOFTWARE:                    no
GENERAL.NM-MANAGED:                     yes
GENERAL.AUTOCONNECT:                    yes
GENERAL.FIRMWARE-MISSING:               no
GENERAL.NM-PLUGIN-MISSING:              no
GENERAL.PHYS-PORT-ID:                   --
GENERAL.CONNECTION:                     --
GENERAL.CON-UUID:                       --
GENERAL.CON-PATH:                       --
GENERAL.METERED:                        unknown
CAPABILITIES.CARRIER-DETECT:            yes
CAPABILITIES.SPEED:                     unknown
CAPABILITIES.IS-SOFTWARE:               no
CAPABILITIES.SRIOV:                     no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.UP:                     yes
INTERFACE-FLAGS.LOWER-UP:               no
INTERFACE-FLAGS.CARRIER:                no
WIRED-PROPERTIES.CARRIER:               off
CONNECTIONS.AVAILABLE-CONNECTION-PATHS: --

##### NetworkManager.state ##############

cat: /var/lib/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.state: No such file or directory

##### NetworkManager config #############

[[/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf]]
[connection]
wifi.powersave = 3

[[/etc/NetworkManager/NetworkManager.conf]]
[main]
plugins=ifupdown,keyfile
[ifupdown]
managed=false
[device]
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-dns-resolved.conf]]
[main]
dns=systemd-resolved

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/10-globally-managed-devices.conf]]
[keyfile]
unmanaged-devices=*,except:type:wifi,except:type:gsm,except:type:cdma

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/20-connectivity-ubuntu.conf]]
[connectivity]
uri=http://connectivity-check.ubuntu.com/

[[/usr/lib/NetworkManager/conf.d/no-mac-addr-change.conf]]
[device-mac-addr-change-wifi]
match-device=driver:rtl8723bs,driver:rtl8189es,driver:r8188eu,driver:8188eu,driver:eagle_sdio,driver:wl
wifi.scan-rand-mac-address=no

##### NetworkManager profiles ###########

##### Netplan config ####################

[/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml]
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager

##### iw reg get ########################

Region: Europe/Tallinn (based on set time zone)

global
country 00: DFS-UNSET
    (2402 - 2472 @ 40), (N/A, 20), (N/A)
    (2457 - 2482 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (2474 - 2494 @ 20), (N/A, 20), (N/A), NO-OFDM, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5170 - 5250 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5250 - 5330 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, AUTO-BW, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5490 - 5730 @ 160), (N/A, 20), (0 ms), DFS, PASSIVE-SCAN
    (5735 - 5835 @ 80), (N/A, 20), (N/A), PASSIVE-SCAN
    (57240 - 63720 @ 2160), (N/A, 0), (N/A)

##### iwlist channels ###################

lo        no frequency information.

enp1s0f1  no frequency information.

usb0      no frequency information.

##### iwlist scan #######################

lo        Interface doesn't support scanning.

enp1s0f1  Interface doesn't support scanning.

usb0      Interface doesn't support scanning.

##### module infos ######################

[cfg80211]
filename:       /lib/modules/5.8.0-43-generic/kernel/net/wireless/cfg80211.ko
description:    wireless configuration support
license:        GPL
depends:        
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
name:           cfg80211
vermagic:       5.8.0-43-generic SMP mod_unload 
parm:           bss_entries_limit:limit to number of scan BSS entries (per wiphy, default 1000) (int)
parm:           ieee80211_regdom:IEEE 802.11 regulatory domain code (charp)
parm:           cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz:Disable 40MHz support in the 2.4GHz band (bool)

##### module parameters #################

[cfg80211]
bss_entries_limit: 1000
cfg80211_disable_40mhz_24ghz: N
ieee80211_regdom: 00

##### /etc/modules ######################

##### modprobe options ##################

[/etc/modprobe.d/amd64-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-ath_pci.conf]
blacklist ath_pci

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf]
blacklist evbug
blacklist usbmouse
blacklist usbkbd
blacklist eepro100
blacklist de4x5
blacklist eth1394
blacklist snd_intel8x0m
blacklist snd_aw2
blacklist prism54
blacklist bcm43xx
blacklist garmin_gps
blacklist asus_acpi
blacklist snd_pcsp
blacklist pcspkr
blacklist amd76x_edac

[/etc/modprobe.d/blacklist-rare-network.conf]
alias net-pf-3 off
alias net-pf-6 off
alias net-pf-9 off
alias net-pf-11 off
alias net-pf-12 off
alias net-pf-19 off
alias net-pf-21 off
alias net-pf-36 off

[/etc/modprobe.d/intel-microcode-blacklist.conf]
blacklist microcode

[/etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf]
remove iwlwifi \
(/sbin/lsmod | grep -o -e ^iwlmvm -e ^iwldvm -e ^iwlwifi | xargs /sbin/rmmod) \
&& /sbin/modprobe -r mac80211

##### rc.local ##########################

grep: /etc/rc.local: No such file or directory

##### pm-utils ##########################

##### udev rules ########################

##### dmesg #############################

[   44.099055] r8169 0000:01:00.1 enp1s0f1: Link is Down
[  329.414323] rndis_host 2-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device, <MAC address>
[  336.163613] rndis_host 2-1:1.0 usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device
[  336.640093] rndis_host 2-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device, <MAC address>
[  567.622119] rndis_host 2-1:1.0 usb0: unregister 'rndis_host' usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device
[  573.930681] rndis_host 2-1:1.0 usb0: register 'rndis_host' at usb-0000:00:14.0-1, RNDIS device, <MAC 'usb0' [IF2]>

########## wireless info END ############
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Ubuntu 20.04 or newer, you’ll need to remove the `bcmwl` drivers and replace them with packages for Broadcom:

```
sudo apt purge bcmwl-kernel-source
sudo apt install broadcom-sta-source broadcom-sta-dkms broadcom-sta-common
```

This should do it for you.

Comment: So I tried these commands.
Removing the drivers didn't work because there weren't any.
Installing the packages seemed to be successful, but after a reboot the wifi problem was still there.